# Powers of elements in rings

Tags: ring-theory

Boolean rings are examples of rings where for any $x$ there exists $n>1$ such that $x^n=x$. (Of course $n=2$ will do.) I would appreciate some other examples.

Comment: Any finite field will do.

Comment: By the way, it might be wise to state your question a bit clearer, for example, "I am looking for rings with this and this property. I know boolean rings are an example. Can anybody give me more examples?"

Comment: I forgot to mention finite fields as examples. I thought of them after writing the question. It would be interesting to have examples with different values of $n$ for different elements $x$.

Comment: I don't know if you are interested in this. It is known that if for any $x$ of $R$ there exists $n(x)\ge 2\in\mathbb N$ such that $x^{n(x)}=x$, then $R$ is commutative. The proof can be seen at http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.dmj/1077465581

Comment: @RodneyColeman, finite fields fall in this last category you mentioned. For example in $\mathbb{F}_7$, $6 = -1$ so that $6^2 = 1$ so that $6^3 = 6$. However the minimal $n$ such that $3^n = 1$ is strictly bigger than 3.

Comment: Following on the comment of @mathlove , every finite commutative ring without zero divisors is a field (can anybody backup this claim?). Since by your hypothesis and the claimof mathlove, your ring is commutative and without zero divisors, every finite example will be a field.

Comment: @Joachim *can anybody backup this claim?* Wedderburn's little theorem says: "finite rings with identity with no (nonzero) zero divisors are fields." I really do mean that you can drop commutativity! But assuming commutativity makes this result a lot easier to prove than WLT. (The simplified version is maybe an undergraduate-level algebra exercise in difficulty.) Regards

Comment: It's worth noting that such a ring is a commutative von Neumann regular ring. The solution below has manufactured a large class of such rings, but it's tantalizing to wonder if a classification is possible. (Since I haven't heard of one, it seems doubtful though.) Can one show that if a direct product of fields $R$ has an $n$ such that $x^n=x$ for all $x$, then the fields must be finite? (If so, it seems like one could consequently prove that there are only finitely many isotypes of fields.)

Comment: @rschwieb , thanks this is very interesting. It's been years, so i forgot the precise statement of WLT.

Comment: One of the reasons for being interested in such rings is that their  prime ideals are maximal.

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned, finite fields are examples. So are the direct sum of any number of finite fields, and the direct product of finite fields (provided that all fields in the product are isomorphic to one of finitely many fields).  Indeed any such ring is commutative and [von Neumann regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) and thus must be a subring of a product of fields.

Comment: Dear universalset: +1, but I'm not sure that an italicized "different" is enough to get your meaning across. It might be good to just write what you mean. Regards

Comment: Good point.  Not sure why I thought that was a good way to say it... Is this better?

Comment: That's probably sufficient. Another try might be "provided that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes among these rings," but I think I like yours better.